# Growing a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, fractals

I have a ruleset of 3x256 rules. Each rule maps to a 3x3 grid of values, which in turn themselves are rules.

Example rules:

```
0 -> [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]  
1 -> [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
```

Seed:

```
[[0]]
```

After 1 iteration:

```
[[0,0,0],
[0,1,0],
[0,0,0]]
```

After 2 iterations:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Now I have a working implementation, however, it's the slowest function in my script. I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic and more efficient way to rewrite this function.

```
def decode(rules,fractal_iterations,seed):
    final_seed_matrix = np.zeros((3,3**fractal_iterations,3**fractal_iterations))

    for i in range(dimensions):
        seed_matrix = np.array([[seed]])
        for j in range(fractal_iterations):
            size_y = seed_matrix.shape[0]
            size_x = seed_matrix.shape[1]
            new_matrix = np.zeros((size_y*rule_size_sqrt,size_x*rule_size_sqrt))

            for y in range(size_y):
                for x in range(size_x):
                    seed_value = seed_matrix[y,x]
                    new_matrix[y*rule_size_sqrt : y*rule_size_sqrt+rule_size_sqrt, x*rule_size_sqrt : x*rule_size_sqrt+rule_size_sqrt] = rules[int(seed_value),i]

            seed_matrix = new_matrix
        final_seed_matrix[i] = seed_matrix

    return np.moveaxis(final_seed_matrix,0,-1)
```

Comment: Perhaps with Cython if you don't stick to pure Python but to a nearly Pythonic code. I don't promise however you can reach a speedier code with Cython, than with other Python algorithm. I am not an expert of Cython.
http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html

Comment: The general rule is to use python-arrays where appending is fast. Then after collecting everything, create an array once.

Comment: Pre-allocating the arrays is fine. The nested `for` loops are the performance killers, but I'm not sure if it's possible to vectorize much here. What is the purpose of the `dimensions` variable and associated outer loop?

Comment: @kazemakase The dimensions variable is for the 3 colour dimensions. It's defined globally, but is supposed to be 3 here in the 4th line.

Comment: Does that mean you iterate over each dimension independently? This could *probably* be vectorized if moved into the inner-most loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an optimized version that uses advanced indexing to select and patch together all rules in one indexing step. This creates a 4D array with the appropriate rule at the position of the pixel it replaces. Flattening that to 2D is then a matter of swapping the middle axes and reshaping. It appears to give the same result as yours, but significantly faster (only tested for integer rules so far):

```
results equal: True
OP       : 24.883304461836815 ms
optimized: 1.093490980565548 ms
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

dimensions = 3
rule_size_sqrt = 3

def decode(rules,fractal_iterations,seed):
    final_seed_matrix = np.zeros((3,3**fractal_iterations,3**fractal_iterations))

    for i in range(dimensions):
        seed_matrix = np.array([[seed]])
        for j in range(fractal_iterations):
            size_y = seed_matrix.shape[0]
            size_x = seed_matrix.shape[1]
            new_matrix = np.zeros((size_y*rule_size_sqrt,size_x*rule_size_sqrt))

            for y in range(size_y):
                for x in range(size_x):
                    seed_value = seed_matrix[y,x]
                    new_matrix[y*rule_size_sqrt : y*rule_size_sqrt+rule_size_sqrt, x*rule_size_sqrt : x*rule_size_sqrt+rule_size_sqrt] = rules[int(seed_value),i]

            seed_matrix = new_matrix
        final_seed_matrix[i] = seed_matrix

    return np.moveaxis(final_seed_matrix,0,-1)

def decode_fast(rules, fractal_iterations, seed):
    rules_int = rules.astype(int)
    seed = np.array([[seed]], dtype=int)
    res = np.empty((3**fractal_iterations, 3**fractal_iterations, dimensions),
                   dtype=rules.dtype)
    for i in range(dimensions):
        grow = seed
        for j in range(1, fractal_iterations):
            grow = rules_int[grow, i].swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(3**j, -1)
        grow = rules[grow, i].swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(3**fractal_iterations, -1)
        res[..., i] = grow
    return res

rules = np.random.randint(0, 4, (4, dimensions, 3, 3))
seed = 1
fractal_iterations = 5
print('results equal:', np.all(decode(rules, fractal_iterations, seed) == decode_fast(rules, fractal_iterations, seed)))

from timeit import repeat
print('OP       :', min(repeat('decode(rules, fractal_iterations, seed)', globals=globals(), number=50))*20, 'ms')
print('optimized:', min(repeat('decode_fast(rules, fractal_iterations, seed)', globals=globals(), number=50))*20, 'ms')
```